# Android orientation change glitch

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, device-orientation, orientation-changes

I encountered weird problem when changing screen orientation rather fast, or when something heavy goes on background. When I call `setContentView(R.layout.main);`on `onConfigurationChanged` (I handle orientation changes myself),after screen is rotated android for a brief moment sets layout for opposite to orientation. For example - when you change orientation layout changes like this **Portrait>Landscape**, but sometimes, in my case, it goes like this **Portrait>Portrait(when phone is already in in landscape position)>Landscape**.

Sometimes you dont even notice this, and sometimes screen shrinks to about 1/3 for a second.
Well, It's not really a big deal, but in my activity I have Coverflow widget (based on Gallery) and to make it look good on most of the screens I set image sizes based on parent container size (in `onSizeChanged` of widget), and when orientation changes goes as described above coverflow widget picks up a **wrong** size.

The only way I see now is to either call onCreate on orientation change (Which I cant do, because of heavy UI populated online), or set a delay on initializing UI (which is ugly).

So I wonder, is there any callback of `setContentView()` or anything else, so I could know when layout is actually ready, so I can init UI.

Or maybe there is another way around?

PS: For some reason this glitch mostly occurs on Desire HD.

Comment: I think I'm seeing the same thing here illustrated by this simple test app:  [Why does onLayout and onSizeChanged get called twice on an orientation change?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696118/369658)

Answer (score 0):

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Is it what you expect?

Comment: And what? I already said, I handle orientation changes by myself.